# ERROR: The database URL has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file deploying jhipster to heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, jhipster

I am new with Jhipster and Heruko. Right now I am trying to deploy a jhipter app in Heroku but I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Liquibase Community 3.9.0 by Datical
[INFO] Starting Liquibase at Tue, 27 Oct 2020 03:18:05 UTC (version 3.9.0 #11 built at Thu May 14 04:03:56 UTC 2020)
[INFO] Settings
----------------------------
[INFO]     driver: null
[INFO]     url: null
[INFO]     username: null
[INFO]     password: *****
[INFO]     use empty password: false
[INFO]     properties file: null
[INFO]     properties file will override? false
[INFO]     prompt on non-local database? false
[INFO]     clear checksums? false
[INFO]     changeLogDirectory: null
[INFO]     changeLogFile: src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
[INFO]     context(s): null
[INFO]     label(s): null
[INFO]     number of changes to apply: 0
[INFO]     drop first? false
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.010 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-27T03:18:05Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.9.0:update (default-cli) on project lacustico: The database URL has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file. -> [Help 1]
```

I'm using MySql as database. The db url, user and password are specify in aplication-prod.xml don't know what am I missing.
Please advise, it has been like 4 days dealing with this issue.

Comment: How did you deploy to heroku? Via the offical sub generator?